# Changing original question, asking follow up questions

Tags: discussion

I answered a question that explained why code in the post wasn't working. OP asked follow up questions and I instructed them to ask a new question. I always  assumed you should ask a new question if your original post was answered but I couldn't find an answer here to link to add proof of my argument.

What's the correct thing to do?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528478/reactive-form-assigned-in-subscription-does-not-detect-valuechanges/40528930?noredirect=1#comment68332933_40528930

Comment: These are called [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/295232) - check the link for possible solutions to your problem.